# Dialogflow - How to find parmater name in slotfilling?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have an intent with 5 **required** parameters for whom I have enabled **web-hook slot-filling**. I need to send some extra payload based on the **'Parameter name'** whose message is prompted back from dialogflow to my API.

But the problem is Dialogflow is not sending this information about active **parameter** back to my API, does anyone have any solution for this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use output context and add the additional information that can be reused for the slot filling.